# Check if service was started as foreground

Tags: android

Is there a way a service can check if it was started as background ( startService() ) or foreground ( startForegroundService()) service ?

Comment: I believe there's no direct way to identify whether its Foreground or Background Service.

Comment: Can you tell the purpose ? May be we can help you some way around.

Comment: the problem is that if the service was started as foreground service but didn't call 'startForeground' then the app is closed by the platform

Comment: So that is not a problem! Its a limitation imposed by newer Android: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: I am aware of this limitation , and I want my service to react accordingly. on some situations I want its runs as background and some as foreground

Comment: Can you define those situations?